# mac finder - how to open alias in a new finder window

Tags: macos, finder, alias, google-drive

I am doing a video project in which I created a folder with a bunch of aliases to files on various spots on my hard drive, so that I could have references to those files all stored in one location but not have to duplicate the actual resources. The problem is these aliases are in a google drive folder, and google drive won't show aliases. So rather than try and track down all those files again - I want to be able to click on the alias and choose "open in  new finder window" or something like that (or be able to copy an alias as an actual file). Is this possible? How?

Comment: You mean right-click an alias and select *Show Original*? Please explain how Google Drive is relevant to finding an alias' original, this isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Google Drive just doesn't show aliases - so because I'm working remotely, I need to use logmein in to access my remote computer, where I can actually see the aliases, and manipulate them in finder to create an actual physical copy in google drive that I can work with locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Finder, you can use Cmd-ctrl-o to open a selected file or folder in a new window. This works on aliases, too: you'll get the target opened in a new Finder window (assuming it was a directory).

Using the terminal, you can use the command `open /path_to/some_alias` to achieve the same effect, or `open /path_to_your_aliases/*` to open them all in new Finder windows all at once. =)

To copy the target files directly, you can use Terminal, or write some AppleScript. (One advantage to such an approach is that processing *all* the aliases at once is no more difficult than processing a single alias.) However, assuming the files in question are actually aliases (rather than symlinks), this is somewhat complicated. If you do want to try it, I can elaborate.